# Google App Script doesn't set Bcc adress

Tags: google-apps-script

I have develop a simple google app script to send an email with bcc I just trying to URL param To, From and subject is set is correctly but, the cc and bcc address are not set properly

[image]

My code snippet is here.

```
function doPost(e) { // change to doPost(e) if you are recieving POST data
var mailId = '';
var mailSubject = '';
var mailBody = '';
var htmlBody = '';
var senderName = '';
var replyToAddress = '';
var bccAddresses = '';

    mailId = e.parameter['Email'];
    mailSubject = e.parameter['Subject'];
    mailBody = e.parameter['MailBody'];
    htmlBody = e.parameter['HtmlBody'];
    senderName = e.parameter['SenderName'];
    replyToAddress = e.parameter['ReplyTo'];
    bccAddresses = e.parameter['bccAddress'];

  Logger.log(':::::::mailId:::::',mailId);

  if(mailId != '' && mailId != null){

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to:mailId, 
      subject:mailSubject, 
      htmlBody:mailBody, 
      bcc:bccAddresses,
      name:senderName,
      replyTo:replyToAddress,
    });  
  }

var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
return ContentService
            .createTextOutput(emailQuotaRemaining);
}

function doGet(request) {
  var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  var result = {
    available: 0
  };
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    request.parameters.prefix + '(' + emailQuotaRemaining + ')')
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

My HTML code is

```
<form method="post" style="display:none;" id="form" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwlMz27gP9vxZA-X58wvxgerhG46A6TEZw33YFe5mvJ0ejFSYQt/exec">
        <input type="text" name="Subject" value="Test Subject" />
        <input type="text" name="MailBody" value="Test Body" />
        <input type="text" name="Email" value="subashc@softsquare.biz" />
        <input type="text" name="SenderName" value="MSCB" />
        <input type="text" name="ReplyTo" value="test@gmail.com" />
        <input type="text" name="bccAddress" value="mscb39@yahoo.com" />
        <textarea name="HtmlBody">Test Body</textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="sub" />
    </form>  
    <button onclick="subForm();">Submit</button>

    <script>
        function subForm() {
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks in Advance,

Subash Chandrabose.M

Comment: Change the logger.log calls to be `Logger.log(':::::::bccAddresses:::::' + bccAddresses);` and then please post a screen capture of the Log (View->Logs) after running the script.  As long as the editor is open your code should populate the Log once that change is made.

Comment: The log always shows **No user logs found. Please run your script and try again.**

Comment: And yet an email is sent?  IF your editor is opened to edit these files, you should see the information in the log. Have you deployed a version as a web app?  If yes, you can run the current code via a link from the Publish dialog.  I know I have been able to read the log when running code from that link.

Comment: Actually My problem is do not set bcc or cc addresses properly. The other  email fields are set properly like subject, to address, sender name and body.

Comment: The syntax in MailApp.sendEmail() looks good.  There must be some error in the values for cc and bcc  These should be a text string, separated by commas, such as "me@gmai.com, you@ail.com"  I was looking for a log to determine if that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Could you put BCC in the options and test.

```
MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, "", {
  htmlBody:mailBody, 
  bcc:bccAddresses,
  name:senderName,
  replyTo:replyToAddress
});
```

Comment: Hi Amit, I tried that method. but its not set bcc address field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you aren't refrencing a bcc adress when you are calling your function..  How are you calling your function? 
*(I would comment but I don't have enough reputation yet)*

Comment: Thanks Johnathan, I called my method from POST method in a HTML form action. Is it make sense?.